# XmlTextWriter: Problems with WhiteSpace

Tags: vb.net, xmlwriter

I'm actually trying to use xmltextwriter to create a xml, but im having certains problems.

This is what i did

```
Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("FactElec.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    writer.WriteStartDocument(False)
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    writer.Indentation = 2
    writer.WriteStartElement("Invoice")

    writer.WriteStartElement("sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal")
    writer.WriteElementString("cbc:id", "1001")
    writer.WriteWhitespace("/n")
    writer.WriteRaw("<cbc:PayableAmount currencyID=""PEN"">" + TotGrav + 
    "</cbc:PayableAmount>/n")
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
    writer.Flush()
    writer.Close()
```

the problem is that i got an error in writer.WriteWhitespace, saying that it needs to be blank, but i need that the next WriteRaw appears in the next line. Just now it appears next to cbc:id

Thanks and sorry if i cannot explain it better.

Update: Or, just in case, if u know how can i add the currencyID=""PEN"" in cbc:PayableAmount, without using WriteRaw, could be better, because that is what is making me all these problems

Comment: Firstly, what specific error are you seeing, what output are you getting, and what output would you like to see?  Secondly, your `/n` looks like it's an attempt at a newline character - that would usually be `\n`, but that doesn't work in VB.  Instead you can use `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Im not getting anything, i show me an error, and i need, in that part, something like this    

<sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
<cbc:ID>1004</cbc:ID>
 <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN">48.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
</sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>

All separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384563.aspx) for creating xml files in little bid cleaner way.

```
Imports <xmlns:sac="http://yoursacnamespace">
Imports <xmlns:cbc="http://yourcbcnamespace">

Public Module XmlInvoiceHelper
    Public Sub SaveWithValue(totGrav As Integer)
        Dim xml As XElement =
        <Invoice>
            <sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
                <cbc:id>1001</cbc:id>
                <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="PEN"><%= totGrav %></cbc:PayableAmount>
            </sac:AdditionalMonetaryTotal>
        </Invoice>

        Using  writer As New XmlTextWriter("YourFile.xml", Encoding.UTF8)
            xml.Save(writer);
        End Using
    End Function
End Module
```

For namespaces `sac` and `cbc` you need add `Imports` line in the beginning of code file to support them for Xml literals code.

Comment: It's not working in this part: 
Using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"YourFile.xml", Encoding.UTF8))     
            xml.Save(writer);

I'm working in vb.net

Comment: Really thanks, you help me a lot with this :) i was suffering because this xml have A LOT of lines, but with this is more easy to do it :)